# Meteor+Angular2 auth issue

Tags: angular, meteor, meteor-accounts, angular-meteor

I am trying to implement the custom auth based the socially [tutorial](https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/angular-material-and-custom-angular-auth-forms).

My app stops working when I add the decorator **InjectUser**, as below:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

import template from "./app.component.html";
import style from "./app.component.scss";

import { InjectUser } from "angular2-meteor-accounts-ui";

@Component({
    selector: "app",
    template,
    styles: [style]
})
@InjectUser('user')
export class AppComponent {
    constructor() {

    }

    logout() {
        Meteor.logout();
    }
}
```

Also, the *tutorial app step19* downloaded files throws error when I try running it.

How do I fix this issue or how can I create a custom login?

Answer (score 0):

`@InjectUser('user')` is added for for user collection access in html part. and i think you are missing one line in your AppComponent.

```
  user: Meteor.User;
```

declare user which you have injected and plz tell us what error you are getting. i will edit my answer if i found your error is because of something else.

Comment: I am following this tutorial: https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/angular-material-and-custom-angular-auth-forms 

I don't see any error in the console.